# Silverlight: Cannot use more than 1MB isolated storage when running out-of-browser

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage, out-of-browser

I'm reading everywhere the running a Silverlight app as out-of-browser allows you to use up to 25MB of isolated storage. I'm writing a 1.6MB file to IS, but get an error saying I've exceeded the storage capacity when it hits 1MB. Yes, I made sure the Out-Of-Browser option is checked on the project settings...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to actually install the out-of-browser application first (open the test HTML file in the BIN folder and right-click on it to get the option). Once this is done, the size is increased to 25 MB. I thought it would do so within debug before installing the app...

Answer (score 4):

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28VS.95%29.aspx) page on MSDN, it appears that you can increase the size with the IncreaseQuotaTo method.

**From MSDN**

A quota group's default size is 1 MB. An application can request to increase the quota group size with the IncreaseQuotaTo method. If the user approves the increased size, that size is the new quota group size that all applications on that domain can share. In addition, Silverlight provides a configuration value that enables you to set the isolated storage size to the maximum allowed value. For more information, see the Isolated Storage section of the Group Policy Settings page.

Answer (score 0):

On the debug page of the project properties in Visual Studio select "Out-of-browser application" as the start action.  This will start the debug session with the app running out of browser.

Comment: Yup, I did that from the beginning, but still ran up against the 1MB limit. Actually, I'm still having problems while debugging (getting the error that I ran out of space), but it works fine when I run a Released version, since I installed my app first thing with it.